# Adding a Month to a Date in a Google Spreadsheet with a Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a Google App Script that adds one month to a date already on a Google Spreadsheet. In the example below I was trying to take the date from cell B2 (1/1/16) and add one month and then place the new date in cell B4 (2/1/16). Using the script below I get the result of 1454313600000 instead of 2/1/16. I haven't been able to figure out what I need to do to get a result of 2/1/16.

```
function myFunction(DateTest) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var value = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
  var a1date = value.getMonth();
  var newdate = value.setMonth(a1date+1);

  sheet.getRange('B4').setValue(newdate);
}
```

Comment: Dates are stored as numbers. I'll wager that if you format the cell as a date it'll be the date you expect.

Comment: What do you mean "add one month"? If the date is January 31st, what should the result be?

Comment: @AlE. When I format the cell as date it is still displaying 1454313600000

Comment: @Normal The date will always be on the first of the month, if the date was January 1st I would like the result to be February 1st.

Comment: Okay. Do you have to use Apps Script for this? The added conversion layers are more of a nuisance with dates; the built-in formulas could do this  task just fine.

Comment: @Normal I'm trying to make a button that will copy data from another Google Sheet, delete that data, and then update the date to the next month. If I can I'd like to be able to do this in the script to make it easier for our full workflow.

Comment: @AlE. You're halfway right: Sheets store dates as the number of days since some day around 1900. But it's only a five-digit number by now (today is 42379). The number 1454313600000 would be about 4 billion years in the future. (It's actually a JavaScript timestamp measured in milliseconds.)

Comment: I learned something today, so that makes it worthwhile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is on JavaScript level, not specific to Apps. The method `setMonth` that you use modifies the date object on which it's called. You don't need any assignment on that line. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) don't even say what `setMonth` is supposed to return, but apparently it returns the millisecond timestamp corresponding to the new date. In any case, this is what works:

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var value = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
  var a1date = value.getMonth();
  value.setMonth((a1date+1) % 12);   // no assignment needed; also, mod 12
  sheet.getRange('B4').setValue(value); 
}
```

Notice that `% 12` is needed to get from December to January.

Answer (score 1):

The formula in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13633692/) increments the month portion of a date by 1, however it will return incorrect and even invalid dates depending on the initial date entered in `B2`.

The correct formula must take into account the differing lengths of months, leap years, as well as whether the month is the last in the year.

For example:

```
2023-12-01 + 1 month ≠ 2023-01-01
2023-01-29 + 1 month ≠ 2023-02-29
```

The correct formula below was posted by @Jazaret in an [answer at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13633692/)

It does essentially the same job as the `EDATE()` spreadsheet function.

Working example where the result variable is written to the log:

```
function workingAddMonth() {
var myDate = new Date("2024-03-31");
var result = myDate.addMonths(1);

 console.log(result)
}

Date.isLeapYear = function (year) { 
    return (((year % 4 === 0) && (year % 100 !== 0)) || (year % 400 === 0)); 
};

Date.getDaysInMonth = function (year, month) {
    return [31, (Date.isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28), 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][month];
};

Date.prototype.isLeapYear = function () { 
    return Date.isLeapYear(this.getFullYear()); 
};

Date.prototype.getDaysInMonth = function () { 
    return Date.getDaysInMonth(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth());
};

Date.prototype.addMonths = function (value) {
    var n = this.getDate();
    this.setDate(1);
    this.setMonth(this.getMonth() + value);
    this.setDate(Math.min(n, this.getDaysInMonth()));
    return this;
};
```

Comment: +10  Great example of when it makes sense to answer a very old (2016) question in spite of an an accepted answer.  I suggested some edits to improve the answer.  Keep contributing!